# Why css doesn't load in jsp file

Tags: css, jsp

I am using JSP form:checkbox and css. When checkbox is checked box should change color to yellow. 
It doesn't work but for form:radiobutton css class is working? What should I do, any ideas?

JSP:

```
<c:forEach var="category" items="${categories}">
                <div class="form-group form-group--checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <form:checkbox path="categories" value="${category.id}" id="categories"
                                       itemLabel="${category.name}"></form:checkbox>

                        <span class="checkbox"></span>
                        <span class="description">${category.name}</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </c:forEach>
```

CSS:

```
form .form-group--checkbox input:checked + .checkbox {
  background-color: #f9c910;
}
```

Comment: Is there a `<form>` around the `<c:forEach>`?

Comment: yes, <form> is around <c:foreach>

Comment: What is interesting is that form:radiobutton is working well

Comment: can you post generated `html` as well ?

Comment: I added whole html

Comment: @JanDuda please [edit] the original question. do not add more information as an answer